# Symfony 3.4.6 - SonataAdmin - configureFromFields - Tabs - Add image on tab

Tags: tabs, sonata-admin, symfony-3.4

I have SonataAdmin.

Is it possible to put an image on the button of the tab (next to the text)?

```
$formMapper
    ->tab('admin.general.tabs.translate_es.label')
        ->with('')
            ->add('name_es', null, [
                'label' => 'admin.entity.crop.fields.name_es.label',
            ])
        ->end()
    ->end()
```

And the label text is: `admin.entity.crop.fields.name_es.label`:

```
<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-400.png" width="16"/> Español
```

In this case, only show tue HTML of the image (`<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-400.png" width="16"/> Español`) not the image!

Answer (score 0):

Put  into a help field

```
->with('')
    ->add('name_es', null, [
        'label' => 'admin.entity.crop.fields.name_es.label',
        'help' => '<img src="https://cdn.countryflags.com/thumbs/spain/flag-400.png" width="16"/>'
    ])
->end()
```